# How to find img in main tag if main exist using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to know how to find all images in main tag if main tag exist ? except just find images that's in out of  tag (I want to make an order to scrape images in main tag if exist and if there is no main tag scrape all images)

**In fact I want to fillter header and footer tag and scrape all images in between.**

```
if find('main'):
    for link in soup.find('main').find_all('img'):
        grabbedImages = link.get('src')
else:
    for link in soup.find_all('img'):
        grabbedImages = link.get('src')
```

Thank you in advance for your guidance.

Comment: Hey @Martin do you resolved it?

Comment: @Martin Did your code raise any errors? In case add the _full traceback_ to the question

Comment: @cards No there is no error thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first IF "find('main')" to "soup.find('main')"

```
if soup.find('main'):
    for link in soup.find('main').find_all('img'):
        grabbedImages = link.get('src')
else:
    for link in soup.find_all('img'):
        grabbedImages = link.get('src')
```